# pdfjsLib not initializing and is undefined

Tags: jquery, pdf.js

included files are

```
<script src="~/Scripts/pdf.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/pdf.worker.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/viewer.js"></script>
```

and i am trying to load pdf using below code

```
var url = 'http://gahp.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/sample.pdf';
var pdfjsLib = window['/Scripts/pdf'];
```

but pdfjsLib not initializing and is undefined

example is here [example](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/)

and please also explane how we are create shortcut using window['something'] object

thanks

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, pdfjsLib is undefined. Did you figure out how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the context in which you're using this module, but, for me, I started experiencing the "pdfjsLib is not defined" issue when I upgraded from Drupal 8 to Drupal 9. It turns out that all I needed was to upgrade the pdf.js library to its latest version. If you are using that library in your solution, visit https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/#download and upgrade your version to the latest stable version. I can't guarantee it'll solve your issue, but it's a simple first step (and it solved my issue).

Answer (score -1):

pdfjsLib not initialized when you folder path is changed 
You have to change path if not default from viewer.js and pdf.worker.js and other libraries